# Android "Unfortunately, .... has stopped" - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm using google-play-services and google maps.

I had this error when i try to debug app on device (samsung S3), on the emulator works OK:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzai.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5119)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4725)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4665)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.wifidivision.newsappennino"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Thi is my `AndroidManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.wifidivision.newsappennino">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="it.wifidivision.newsappennino.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="it.wifidivision.newsappennino.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="it.wifidivision.newsappennino.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="it.wifidivision.newsappennino.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:name=".NewsAppennino"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Aggiunto per Parse Push Notifications -->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="it.wifidivision.newsappennino" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MappaLuoghi"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mappa_luoghi" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MappaItinerario"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mappa_itinerario"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: clean your project and retry

Comment: Android Studio these days is very unstable, even stable builds. Just clean, rebuild and then try run.

Comment: i clean the project and retry but i had the same error

Comment: Did you initialized multidex in Application properly? If you have instant run enabled, try to uninstall app, disable instant run, clean project and run again. BTW include whole play services library or just separate modules not both at the same time in your build.gradle file.

Comment: I initialize multiplex in this way: MultiDex.install(this);    Is the correct way?

Comment: @PedrettiAndrea yes. Did you try to disable instant run? Did you try to cleanup your build.gradle?  You have two multidex dependencies and you also included whole playservices and playservices maps module. As I said you should include whole playservices package or separate modules. If you chose only maps maybe multidex won't be necessary anymore. So remove last two "compile..." lines from your build.gradle and try to rebuild.